# How to handle Redis connection error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, redis, backend

```
const redis = require("redis");
const session = require("express-session");
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);

const REDIS_HOST = process.env.REDIS_HOST || "localhost"
const REDIS_PORT = process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379

let redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: REDIS_HOST,
  port: REDIS_PORT
});

module.exports = session({
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
  secret: "super-secret-key", // TBD: grab from env
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    secure: false // require HTTPS in production
  }
});
```

`

```
none
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to 192.168.101.47:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.101.47:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (/mnt/d/Work/TimoBakker_PeterRahman/skrollo/skrollo/node_modules/redis/index.js:406:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Work/TimoBakker_PeterRahman/skrollo/skrollo/node_modules/redis/index.js:279:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',   address: '192.168.101.47',   port: 6379 }
```

`

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! Please use the formatting possibilities.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?